# What factors would allow people here to acquire more than 200 reputation points per day?

Tags: discussion

I understand there is a 200 point per day cap on reputation but there are exceptions that would allow for more. I assume one is acceptance of an answer and another is for a bounty. What are the other ways that more than 200 can be awarded. I see some people who gather 290-305 rep points per day. How is that possible?

Comment: Too bad we can't spread our points out over several days. I just earned over 800 points in the last 3 days, but can't receive them. :-( Wish I could spread those points out over future days where I earn less than 200.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle you can earn an *unlimited* amount of points per day. In practice, the realistic limits are below;

**Upvotes** - These are limited to 200 rep per day.

**Bounty awards** - Theoretically unlimited but since there are usually only 400-1000 rep points worth of "bounty" questions available, that represents something of a limit.

**Accepted answers** - Theoretically unlimited but realistically you're unlikely to have more than 4-5 accepted answers in a day.

**Association bonuses** - Not added to your cap level but also not shown on your rep graph.

The single highest number of reps gained in a day is <s>560</s> 760, primarily from a 500 point bonus. The highest number of reps gained in a day without any bonuses is 350.

http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/110083/most-rep-gained-in-a-single-day

Comment: Interesting. Why was I not on that list with my paltry 215?

Comment: @Morgan - You are on that list. If there was no cap, you'd have received 410 rep points that day

Comment: Oh I see it now, thanks. I missed that lonely little anchovy, sandwiched between all those big fish.

Comment: You missed +2 from accepting answers you asked.

Comment: Note that the *order* you get this rep in matters. If you get accepts *before* you hit 200 for the day, they count against the rep cap.

Comment: @SSumner - No longer correct

Comment: @Richard - when did this change? I haven't been following SE's update news.

Comment: @SSumner - Dunno. Before I joined at end-2003

Comment: @Richard - you mean 2013, right? :P

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the [help centre page on reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. **Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.**

These exceptions are the same across all Stack Exchange sites.

On a user page, you can see a breakdown of the user’s reputation, and where they earned it, by clicking on the "Reputation" tab or appending `?tab=reputation` to the URL.

For example, your reputation breakdown can be found at

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/13090/morgan?tab=reputation

Everything that affects your rep – voting, accepted/accepting answers, bounties, and so on – are listed here, grouped by day so you can see how a particular user scored more than 200 rep in a single day.