# Do offered bounties count against the 200/day rep cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

Related: [What factors would allow people here to acquire more than 200 reputation points per day?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/what-factors-would-allow-people-here-to-acquire-more-than-200-reputation-points)
So receiving bounties doesn't apply against the limit.

Sorry if this one is duplicate too.
When you offer a bounty, does that come off the daily rep limit?

Example:  You earn 250 point in a day for normal up/down votes etc (normally capped to 200) and also offer a +50 bounty.   The 50 point come off right away.   At the of the day if your reputation +200 or +150?

I checked the help article, but it's not clear to me which way it goes.   I *think* the answer **should be** +150, but I **think** the answer might be +200.

(If it's +200, it means that on days where you're earning lots of votes, you can essentially offer bounties free of charge !)

Comment: I'd have to dig through my history to find an example, but rep is typically calculated in order of event occurrence. I've hit the cap, missed rep gains, then gotten a downvote, lost rep, and then had to get another upvote to make up for the missing rep even though I had missed rep earlier. It stands to reason that the bounty would be subtracted when you offered it. In your example, it would be 200.

Comment: @phantom42:   OK, but even if it's in order, it means that if I'm about to hit the cap, or if I'm confident I will of a particular day (like today), I might as well offer a bounty somewhere.

Comment: Downvoter:  please explain.   IMO, this is a legitimate question and I haven't found the answer despite looking.

Comment: i would actually wait until you hit the rep cap before doing it, even if you're confident that you will regain it. hitting the rep cap enough times earns badges. in the possible event that you end up *not* regaining enough to cover the bounty, you'll still have technically hit the cap and made progress for the badges.

Comment: @phantom42:   That is some next-level 'taking advantage' of the system

Comment: @phatom42:   Screw it -- performing the experiment now.

Comment: The bounty comes off of your daily **capped** total. In effect, it changes your cap to 200 *minus the bounty you've offered*. It is, therefore theoretically possible to hit the repcap by posting a bounty and winning a larger bounty in the same day.

Comment: @Richard:  Ah.  I would have imagined that, but it makes sense.

Comment: @phanton42:  ... ha ha, except that @ Praxis just undid my experiment by awarding me a bounty.   Oh well.

Answer (score 5):

As @Richard explained in a comment, instead of thinking of receiving bounties as being exempt from the rep cap limit, it better to think of it like this:

Offering and claiming bounties **both affect the rep cap limit** in the amount equal to their value.

Offering a +50 bounty reduces your cap to 150 and simultaneously reduces your rep by 50.

Earning a +50 bounty raises your cap to +250 and awards you +50.

In his example, if you offer a +50 bounty and earn a +100 bounty, you will have a net gain of +50 and your rep cap for the day will be 250.

Comment: @Richard:   Did I understand right?

Comment: This sounds spot on. As soon as I'm back at desk, I'll link to the relevant meta post on the main meta site

Comment: @Richard should this be added to the main help page on rep or is it too confusing/detailed?